# Dynamic graphic made by pulling images from a database?

Tags: image, dynamic

http://getvideoartwork.com/

How hard would it be for the site owner here to write code to dynamically pull cover art from the database and make the front page graphic?

If nothing else, could you pull random images from the database and output them and style them with CSS3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not hard. With a scripting language, you query the image data from the database, send a header like "image/png" to the browser, and then send the image data. I personally would store the images as files and put the filenames in the database. Then, my script would just pick a random filename out of the database. For that matter, if my image directory only had viable images, I could just pick a random file from the directory. There are many more ways to pick a random image.